# Formatting a bash cat pipe to mail command

Tags: bash, formatting, sendmail

When I wrote this script it works just fine.  What it does is it diffs two file
and if the diff fails that indicates that their is no change between the todays file
and the previous days file. That menas the the download is stale.
However when I to email it it is not formatted. I treid putting in a newline
so that the email is legible. But the mail function does not work.  The file is
to garbled to read.

```
#!/bin/bash
dayofweek=$(/bin/date +%w)
today=$(/bin/date +%Y.%m.%d_)
yesterday=$(/bin/date -d '1 day ago' +%Y.%m.%d_)
destination="/sbclocal/stmevt3/dailymetrics/EQ_PERFORMANCE/"

file1=OPTS_TRIP_TRIP_csv_Oct2014.csv
file2=OPTS_TRIPnon-penny1-20_TRIPnon-penny1-20_Oct2014.csv
file3=OPTS_TRIPnon-penny21-50_TRIPnon-penny21-50_Oct2014.csv
file4=OPTS_TRIPnon-penny51-100_TRIPnon-penny51-100_Oct2014.csv
file5=OPTS_TRIPpenny1-20_TRIPpenny1-20_Oct2014.csv
file6=OPTS_TRIPpenny21-50_TRIPpenny21-50_Oct2014.csv
file7=OPTS_TRIPpenny51-100_TRIPpenny51-100_Oct2014.csv


for i in $file1 $file2 $file3 $file4 $file5 $file6 $file7
do
if diff $destination$today$i $destination$yesterday$i > /dev/null ; then
    printf "$today$i may be stale - please notify production\n" >> /tmp/eq_diffs.$today
sleep 2
else
echo " " > /dev/null
fi
done

#think we might have to do a if file exists
cat /tmp/eq_diffs.$today | mail -s "EQ performance diffs" casper@casper.com
```

Comment: `else echo " " > /dev/null` is entirely useless, just drop it.

Comment: What do you mean by "[the] email ... is not formatted" exactly?

Comment: there is no newline after "stale" - so it just goes to OPTS_TRIP_TRIP_csv_Oct2014.csv is stale OPTS_TRIPnon-penny1-20_TRIPnon-penny1-20_Oct2014.csv is stale OPTS_TRIPnon-penny21-50_TRIPnon-penny21-50_Oct2014.csv is stale

Comment: This may be the fault of your mail reading program.  You're sending a plain text email with newlines but it's being interpreted as HTML.  Try a different mail client.

Comment: Try using `\r\n` in the email instead of `\n`. I believe that's the official line ending for email messages.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Moreover, the posted code and your sample output in the comment do not match (`may be` vs. `is`, `- please notify production` missing). You should post the code that you really used.